# Will the Star Wars galaxy run out of space for planets?

Tags: star-wars, planets

I know that the average galaxy has over 400 billion stars and most stars have planets around it so it seems foolish to think the writers would ever run out of planets. It’s just for the suspension of my belief; Star Wars adds new planets constantly all the time and eventually it’s going to get confusing when there is so much “real estate” and not enough galaxy to physically hold it. On Wookieepedia, someone used AutoWikiBrowser to get an approximate amount of 5,291 planets so far covered in Star Wars storytelling since 1977

What could I tell my headcanon in the future when Star Wars runs out of space for new planets? I may be a bit silly and the number of 5000+ is just a drop in the bucket for a galaxy but I want to be prepared nonetheless.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Surely you can take a billion, divide by 5 000 and multiply it by 45 years.  How old do you plan on getting?  I'm not clear on the point of this question.

Comment: It seems like every star in the Star Wars universe has at least one habitable planet or moon. No risk of running out the next million years or more.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Even if they're not habitable it doesn't seem to stop things like droid manufacturing or strip mining

Comment: It's kind of an open-ended speculative question. Your real question here is "How many planets can Star Wars fans be expected to keep track of?" which is not really a factual question and may not be on topic for this site

Comment: 1) assume the Star Wars galaxy is similar to the Milky Way. 2) do a web search for “how many planets in the Milky Way”.

Answer (score 1):

The Star Wars universe exists in more than one galaxy.

[image: Picture of Luke pointing at a viewscreen with more several galaxies of varying sizes.]

<sup>Copyright Lucasfilm LTD, 1977. Fair usage.</sup>

The Kaminoans' home planet is in the [Rishi Maze](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rishi_Maze), a dwarf galaxy in a decaying orbit near the main one.

The [Yuuzhan Vong](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong#Origins_of_%22Yuuzhan_Vong%22) come from extra-galactic (at least outside the "main" galaxy)  space, originating in the same galaxy as [Zonama Sekot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zonama_Sekot/Legends), the sentient, force-using planet-entity.

The pilot [Taka Jamoreesa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Taka_Jamoreesa) liked to publicise themselves (they're declared non-binary) as "wanted in 18 galaxies". It may have been hyperbole and signifying they're better travelled than they were, but the implication of many galaxies is still there.

The issue of running-out of planets in the galaxy is sidestepped by there being multiple galaxies. The question becomes "will they run out of galaxies?" - to which the answer it, I've no idea what their maximum possible range is.